# image captcha in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing my project in CodeIgniter. I am trying to call `captcha.php` file in index file.This captcha file in folder files. Currently, the captcha image is not viewing. I need to display random numbers in image.

**captcha.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$string = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $string .= chr(rand(97, 122));
}

$_SESSION['random_number'] = $string;

$dir = 'fonts/';

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(165, 50);

// random number 1 or 2
$num = rand(1,2);
if($num==1)
{
    $font = "PT_SANS-BOLD_1.TTF"; // font style
}
else
{
    $font = "PT_SANS-ITALIC_1.TTF";// font style
}

// random number 1 or 2
$num2 = rand(1,2);
if($num2==1)
{
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 113, 193, 217);// color
}
else
{
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 163, 197, 82);// color
}

$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // background color white
imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,399,99,$white);

imagettftext ($image, 30, 0, 10, 40, $color, $dir.$font, $_SESSION['random_number']);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);

?>

in html file

<img src="<?= base_url();?>files/captcha.php" alt="" id="captcha" />
```

Comment: is this codeigniter captcha or custom captcha?

Comment: jquery captcha [link] (http://www.99points.info/2010/08/ajax-stylish-captcha-and-contact-form-using-jquery-and-php/)

Comment: from this link i took that captcha

Comment: can you paste your controller and view.

Comment: what your console says about the `src` of img

Comment: view   <div>Captcha(Spam Protection Code)* 
          <div id="wrap">
                  <img src="<?= base_url(); ?>files/captcha.php" alt="" id="captcha" />
       <br clear="all" />
   <input name="code" type="text" id="code">
 </div>
 <img src="<?= base_url();?>images/refresh.jpg" width="25" alt="" id="refresh" />
  
 <br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />
 <label>&nbsp;</label></div>

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question but alternative you could opt for.

So many captcha scripts are already available may be you can use some of that instead of coding it again.

Check [this](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/php-captcha-security-images/)

If you do go for this option then do make sure that fonts are placed in right places.

Comment: what you said i have tried still it not displaying its content in the image

Comment: <img src="<?= base_url();?>captcha.php?width=100&height=40&characters=5" />  like this only i need to give